# Assign empty value based on a zip list python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a df like this:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan, np.nan, 'w', np.nan, 'y', np.nan],
                 'B': [np.nan, 'G',   'G', np.nan, 'R', 'R'   ]})
# And I zipped the unique values of the two groups together

univalue=zip(df.A.dropna().unique().tolist(), df.B.dropna().unique().tolist())
```

I want to assign values to column A if values in B are not nan, column A has the coordinate value in the zip list. So that the df will be like below. Is there any way to do that?

```
> df
A     B
nan   nan
'w'   'G'
'w'   'G'
nan   nan
'y'   'R'
'y'   'R'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can create a mapping dictionary and then use `.map` to assign to column "A":

```py
univalue = dict(zip(df.B.dropna().unique(), df.A.dropna().unique()))

df["A"] = df["B"].map(univalue)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     A    B
0  NaN  NaN
1    w    G
2    w    G
3  NaN  NaN
4    y    R
5    y    R
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's what I want!